# ClassCast exception when updating value through TableView

Tags: java, javafx, gtfs

Context: Lab using the google transit GTFS API. Using a table view to display route data, and I want to make the data editable from the table. I've succeeded in doing that when the property is a String(route ID and route long name), but the code that makes a cell editable throws an error for non-String properties.

Table Code:

```
table = new TableView<>();
    ObservableList data = FXCollections.observableList(routes);
    table.setItems(data);
    table.setEditable(true);
```

Code for color data column:

```
TableColumn routeColorCol = new TableColumn("Route Color");
    routeColorCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("route_color"));
    routeColorCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    routeColorCol.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent t){
            ((Route) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                    t.getTablePosition().getRow())
            ).setRoute_color((Color)t.getNewValue());
        }
    });
```

I add the table to a Vbox and onto a tab pane. The stacktrace I get doesn't point anywhere to my code, so I'm at a loss.

Stacktrace:

```
Oct 21, 2018 4:39:37 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 9.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.141
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.paint.Color cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at javafx.util.converter.DefaultStringConverter.toString(DefaultStringConverter.java:34)
at javafx.scene.control.cell.CellUtils.getItemText(CellUtils.java:100)
at javafx.scene.control.cell.CellUtils.updateItem(CellUtils.java:201)
at javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell.updateItem(TextFieldTableCell.java:204)
at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:663)
at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:468)
at javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:116)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkin.resizeColumnToFitContent(TableViewSkin.java:241)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableViewSkin.resizeColumnToFitContent(TableViewSkin.java:54)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableColumnHeader.doColumnAutoSize(TableColumnHeader.java:531)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableColumnHeader.updateScene(TableColumnHeader.java:474)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableColumnHeader.handlePropertyChanged(TableColumnHeader.java:314)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableColumnHeader.lambda$new$49(TableColumnHeader.java:149)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler$1.changed(MultiplePropertyChangeListenerHandler.java:55)
at javafx.beans.value.WeakChangeListener.changed(WeakChangeListener.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:81)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.java:74)
at javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:102)
at javafx.scene.Node$ReadOnlyObjectWrapperManualFire.fireSuperValueChangedEvent(Node.java:831)
at javafx.scene.Node.invalidatedScenes(Node.java:883)
at javafx.scene.Node.setScenes(Node.java:921)
at javafx.scene.Parent$1.onChanged(Parent.java:269)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.TrackableObservableList.lambda$new$29(TrackableObservableList.java:45)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.setAll(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:90)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.setAll(VetoableListDecorator.java:116)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.NestedTableColumnHeader.updateContent(NestedTableColumnHeader.java:487)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.NestedTableColumnHeader.updateTableColumnHeaders(NestedTableColumnHeader.java:317)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.NestedTableColumnHeader.checkState(NestedTableColumnHeader.java:544)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.NestedTableColumnHeader.computePrefHeight(NestedTableColumnHeader.java:427)
at javafx.scene.Parent.prefHeight(Parent.java:929)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.prefHeight(Region.java:1435)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableHeaderRow.computePrefHeight(TableHeaderRow.java:331)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableHeaderRow.computeMinHeight(TableHeaderRow.java:324)
at javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:957)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1401)
at javafx.scene.control.SkinBase.computeMinHeight(SkinBase.java:254)
at javafx.scene.control.Control.computeMinHeight(Control.java:489)
at javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:957)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1401)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeChildMinAreaHeight(Region.java:1697)
at javafx.scene.layout.VBox.getAreaHeights(VBox.java:436)
at javafx.scene.layout.VBox.computeContentHeight(VBox.java:518)
at javafx.scene.layout.VBox.computeMinHeight(VBox.java:396)
at javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:957)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1401)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.computeChildPrefAreaHeight(Region.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane.computeHeight(AnchorPane.java:297)
at javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane.computeMinHeight(AnchorPane.java:246)
at javafx.scene.Parent.minHeight(Parent.java:957)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.minHeight(Region.java:1401)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.boundedNodeSizeWithBias(Region.java:1917)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.layoutInArea(Region.java:2323)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.layoutInArea(Region.java:2238)
at javafx.scene.layout.Region.layoutInArea(Region.java:2179)
at javafx.scene.layout.StackPane.layoutChildren(StackPane.java:342)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:354)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$404(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.paint.Color cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at javafx.util.converter.DefaultStringConverter.toString(DefaultStringConverter.java:34)
at javafx.scene.control.cell.CellUtils.getItemText(CellUtils.java:100)
at javafx.scene.control.cell.CellUtils.updateItem(CellUtils.java:201)
at javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTableCell.updateItem(TextFieldTableCell.java:204)
at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.updateItem(TableCell.java:663)
at javafx.scene.control.TableCell.indexChanged(TableCell.java:468)
at javafx.scene.control.IndexedCell.updateIndex(IndexedCell.java:116)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.updateCells(TableRowSkinBase.java:533)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkinBase.init(TableRowSkinBase.java:147)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TableRowSkin.<init>(TableRowSkin.java:64)
at javafx.scene.control.TableRow.createDefaultSkin(TableRow.java:212)
at javafx.scene.control.Control.impl_processCSS(Control.java:872)
at javafx.scene.Node.processCSS(Node.java:9058)
at javafx.scene.Node.applyCss(Node.java:9155)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.setCellIndex(VirtualFlow.java:1964)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCell(VirtualFlow.java:1797)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.getCellLength(VirtualFlow.java:1879)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.computeViewportOffset(VirtualFlow.java:2528)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(VirtualFlow.java:1189)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1087)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1093)
at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:552)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePulseListener.pulse(Scene.java:2397)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.lambda$runPulse$30(Toolkit.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.runPulse(Toolkit.java:354)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.firePulse(Toolkit.java:381)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:510)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.pulse(QuantumToolkit.java:490)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$runToolkit$404(QuantumToolkit.java:319)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used raw type which has made this possible to compile, but type inconsistency happened during runtime. Your `routeColorCol` is supposed to display `javafx.scene.paint.Color` values, but your cell factory callback is written to read `String` values - this is what caused the `ClassCastException` at runtime.

From [`TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html#forTableColumn()):

> Provides a TextField that allows editing of the cell content when the
>   cell is double-clicked, or when TableView.edit(int,
>   javafx.scene.control.TableColumn) is called. **This method will only
>   work on TableColumn instances which are of type String**.

You should use the overload method [`TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(StringConverter)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html#forTableColumn(javafx.util.StringConverter)).

```
routeColorCol.setCellFactory(
    TextFieldTableCell.<Foo, Color> forTableColumn(new StringConverter<Color>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Color object) {
            return object != null ? object.toString() : "";
        }

        @Override
        public Color fromString(String string) {
            return Color.valueOf(string);
        }
    }
));
```